# Email service uses DKIM, but OpenDKIM cannot be started

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta, dkim, opendkim

The email service can be used normally, but the dkim signature part is still missing.
Refer to multiple guides, such as the two below.

https://blog.csdn.net/yetugeng/article/details/83996397 (Chinese website)

https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/dkim-setup-failed/117124/2 (Japanese website)

---

The error is reported as a configuration problem.

```
Aug  8 14:27:19 saikano postfix/smtpd[105588]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8891: Connection refused
```

```
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: Stopped DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 08 15:29:23 saikano.top systemd[1]: Failed to start DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
```

---

Reconfigured a few times and looked for similar issues.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/unable-to-start-opendkim-service-for-mail-server-4175669110/

https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/dkim-setup-failed/117124

Try to find out the problem according to the answer, but the result is unexpected. No such file or directory.

Use journalctl to find problem. `journalctl -u opendkim.service`

```
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top systemd[1]: Stopped DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top systemd[1]: Started DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top opendkim[103885]: /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private: open(): No such file or directory
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top opendkim[103885]: opendkim: /etc/opendkim.conf: /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private: open(): No such file or directory
Aug 08 13:55:41 saikano.top systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
```

But the file is here, this is completely different from these two questions!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBghR.png)

Comment: https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=milter+status%3D78%2FCONFIG&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english